# How to use MATLAB optimization toolbox with functions outside MATLAB?

Tags: optimization, matlab

I want to utilize the optimization toolbox of MATLAB, namely the genetic algorithm.

But my function is an executible, which I wrote in C, which takes a text file as input. In this input file the variables can be set. So I want MATLAB to modify this text file, run the executible, and take the result in an iteration. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call C, C++, or FORTRAN code in MATLAB by compiling your code into a MATLAB Executable called a MEX-file : http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1622.html

Then you would have to call this MEX-file in your fitness function.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `*.exe` files with the `!` command.

Create loop in MATLAB where you will write something to `*.txt`, then run the C program with `!name.exe`, and read results in iterations.